# Invalid Syntax in Python for RPG game

Tags: python

I'm relatively new to Python, and while in the process of creating a basic python RPG wordquest type game. I keep getting an invalid syntax on `def showInstructions():`.

```
rooms = {
        1 : {   "name"  :   "Hall"  },
        2 : {   "name"  :   "Bedroom" },
        3 : {   "name"  :   "Kitchen" },
        4 : {   "name"  :   "Bathroom" }

def showInstructions():
    #The Main Menu
    print ("Mr Bailey's Nightmare!")
    print ("======================")
    print ("Commands:")
    print ("go [direction]'")

def showStatus
    #shows player stats, essentially current room
    print ("---------------------------------------------------------")
    print ("You are in the " + rooms[currentRoom]["name"]
    print ("---------------------------------------------------------")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to close `rooms` dict:

```
rooms = {
    1 : {   "name"  :   "Hall"  },
    2 : {   "name"  :   "Bedroom" },
    3 : {   "name"  :   "Kitchen" },
    4 : {   "name"  :   "Bathroom" }
```

needs

```
}
```

so

```
rooms = {
    1 : {   "name"  :   "Hall"  },
    2 : {   "name"  :   "Bedroom" },
    3 : {   "name"  :   "Kitchen" },
    4 : {   "name"  :   "Bathroom" }
}
```

also your syntax is messed up at `showStatus`

```
def showStatus(currentRoom): # is this the right argument?
    #shows player stats, essentially current room
    print ("---------------------------------------------------------")
    print ("You are in the " + rooms[currentRoom]["name"])
    print ("---------------------------------------------------------")
```